# Как вытащить Hex значения из soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='frame ctooltip')
```

Получаю вот такой результат:

```html
<div class="frame ctooltip">
    <div style="background: #0A1C28"></div>
    <div style="background: #41848F"></div>
    <div style="background: #72A7A3"></div>
    <div style="background: #97C0B7"></div>
    <div style="background: #EEE9D1"></div>
</div>
<div class="frame ctooltip">
    <div style="background: #F19CA2"></div>
    <div style="background: #F8D7D0"></div>
    <div style="background: #FFE9CD"></div>
    <div style="background: #BFE9FF"></div>
    <div style="background: #B7D7D9"></div>
</div>
```

Как из него вытащить Hex значения, сгруппированными по 5 шт.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text = """
<div class="frame ctooltip">
<div style="background: #0A1C28"></div>
<div style="background: #41848F"></div>
<div style="background: #72A7A3"></div>
<div style="background: #97C0B7"></div>
<div style="background: #EEE9D1"></div>
</div>, <div class="frame ctooltip">
<div style="background: #F19CA2"></div>
<div style="background: #F8D7D0"></div>
<div style="background: #FFE9CD"></div>
<div style="background: #BFE9FF"></div>
<div style="background: #B7D7D9"></div>
</div>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

for div in root.select('div.frame.ctooltip'):
    items = [x['style'].split()[-1] for x in div.select('div')]
    print(items)
```

Консоль:

```
['#0A1C28', '#41848F', '#72A7A3', '#97C0B7', '#EEE9D1']
['#F19CA2', '#F8D7D0', '#FFE9CD', '#BFE9FF', '#B7D7D9']
```